# Sorting an array with more than two states

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I try to sorting an array but the output is not this, what I want.

I have an array like this:

```
var myArray = [
    {
       ...
       "foo": false,
       "bar": true,
       ...
    },
    {
       ...
       "foo": true,
       "bar": false,
       ...
    },
    {
       ...
       "foo": true,
       "bar": false,
       ...
    },
    {
       ...
       "foo": false,
       "bar": false,
       ...
    },
    ...
];
```

and I want sort this array this way

```
myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    var foo = a.foo;
    var bar = b.bar;

    if(foo === false && bar === true) {
        // this should sort on top
        return -1;
    }

    if(foo === false && bar === false) {
        // this should sort as second
        return 0;
    }

    if(foo === true && bar === true) {
        // this should sort as third
        return 0;
    }

    if(foo === true && bar === false) {
        // this should sort as last
        return 1;
    }
});
```

I think I have a logical problem with `sort` function.

What I want as output is I comment it in the if comments for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a weightage property to the array objects based on the existing conditions. Like

```
var tempArr = myArray.map(function(obj) {
    var foo = obj.foo;
    var bar = obj.bar;

    if (foo === false && bar === true) {
        // this should sort on top
        obj.weightage = 1;
    }

    if (foo === false && bar === false) {
        // this should sort as second
        obj.weightage = 2;
    }

    if (foo === true && bar === true) {
        // this should sort as third
        obj.weightage = 3;
    }

    if (foo === true && bar === false) {
        // this should sort as last
        obj.weightage = 4;
    }

    return obj;
});
```

and then use the sort function on array

```
tempArr = tempArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.weightage - b.weightage;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript standard does not define the behavior for `Array.sort()` when it encounters multiple values a, b with `compareFunction(a, b) == 0`. Most JavaScript engines use a stable sorting algorithm which guarantees to keep the relative position of such elements after sorting the same as before.

This explains why returning `0` does not produce your desired result.

You would need to establish a relative ordering of all your relevant elements and only return `0` when the order really doesn't matter.